# xslt param conditional check

Tags: c#, xslt

I have a:

```
<xsl:param name="SomeFlag" />
```

In my XSLT template, I want to do a conditional check on SomeFlag. Currently I'm doing it as:

```
<xsl:if test="$SomeFlag = true"> SomeFlag is true! </xsl:if>
```

Is this how we evaluate the the flag?

I'm setting the param in C# as:

```
xslarg.AddParam("SomeFlag", String.Empty, true);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:if test="$SomeFlag = true">
> ```

This tests if `$SomeFlag` is equal to the string value of the element named "true", which is the first child of the current node.

**What you want is**:

```
<xsl:if test="$SomeFlag = true()">
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Dimitre, but have an addition:

In your case you can just use:

```
<xsl:if test="$SomeFlag"> SomeFlag is true! </xsl:if>
```

But I usually use 1 and 0 for boolean flags when the flags are supposed to be evaluated in XSLT, especially when I take the value from an attribute or an element content.

This allow me to test conditions by casting to numbers (and then implicitly to boolean) instead of comparison to a string literal:

```
<xsl:if test="number($SomeFlag)"> SomeFlag is true! </xsl:if>
```

Comment: I never suggested comparing to a strung literal! Please, read my answer and understand it. Also, note that the OP sets the value to be tested from C# and uses a *boolean* value! So, your addition (while generally useful), does not answer the question.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev: I do understand your answer, my idea is just to use 0 and 1 instead of boolean values. So that if the OP would serialize the value into the input tree instead of passing as parameter, the approach would stay the same.